# No se pudo establecer una conexión con un host de correos desde laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando enviar correos con laravel, pero me regresa el siguiente error

```
"Connection could not be established with host mail.mundoreloj.com.co [Connection refused #111]"
```

Comment: Que hosting estas usando? Creo que podria ser problema de la configuracion de los registros en el hosting

Comment: eso o las variables en el .env

Comment: si pero ya lo e configurado de mil maneras inclusive con mi propia cuenta de gmail pero sigue igual

Comment: prueba desde el ordenador donde esta la aplicacion (entiendo que tu ordenador) a hacer un `telnet mail.mundoreloj.com.co 25`. Si no te responde, puede ser cosa de tener el puerto 25 cerrado en tu salida. prueba el mismo telnet hacia el puerto 587. Con esto podras descartar que sea cosa de la configuracion de la app.

Comment: probe con los que me decian que era el 26 y el 465 tambien probe con gmail con el 587 tampoco